# Why is this wedge product equal to zero?

Tags: exterior-algebra, exterior-derivative

I don't understand why
$de^{1}\wedge e^{3}-e^{1}\wedge de^{3}=0$
(d is the exterior derivative)

Could somebody please explain this to me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think this follows from the following formula:

> If $\alpha$ is a k-form and $\beta$ is a form, then
>
> $$d(\alpha \land \beta) = d \alpha \land \beta + (-1)^k \alpha \land d
> \beta$$

Comment: With the additional assumption that $d(e_1\wedge e_3)$ is 0.

Comment: Yes, but since $e_1, e_3$ were not defined in the question it is hard to tell.

Comment: @NDewolf 
The additional assumption does not hold.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta The additional assumption does not hold

Comment: Maybe you should explain then what $e_1$ and $e_3$ are? It is impossible that this assumption does not hold. The formula above shows that it MUST hold if your claim is true (unless $e_1$ is a form of even degree).

Comment: @EpsilonDelta $e_1$ is just the first vector of the standard basis.
The question is to compute $d\omega$ where $\omega=e_1\wedge e_3$

Comment: And is $e_3$ also a standard basis element?

Comment: Makes no sense. You take the exterior derivative of forms, not of vectors (unless you identify the vector with a constant function, which is a zero-form)

Comment: @NDewolf Yes, $e_1,...,e_n$ are the standard basis vectors

Comment: Give your definition of exterior derivative pls.

Comment: I figured it out. The exterior derivatives of $e_1, e_2, ..., e_n$ are equal to themselves. so $de_1=e_1$ and $de^3=e^3$